# crash using UITextfield and undo

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

Today I finished my first application and I am in the process of testing my app. Well, I found a bug that I can't find from where it comes. Inside my app, I have two `UITextfields`. When the user fills one of them, the other autocompletes using the delegate method  `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`
Here is the method. When the user types anything inside any of the textfields and press the undo button on iPad keyboard or shake the iPhone and then press the undo, my application crashes. Here is the error I receive.

```
(Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSBigMutableString substringWithRange:]: Range {0, 2} out of bounds; string length 0').
```

I would really appreciate your help here.

```
-(BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    NSString *stringToValidate = [[textField text] stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    if ([stringToValidate isEqualToString:@""]) {

        self.scoreToAddOfTeam1.text = nil;

        self.scoreToAddOfTeam2.text = nil;



        return YES;

    }

    if ([self validateInputsInsideAnNSString:stringToValidate]) {

        if (textField == self.scoreToAddOfTeam1) {

            self.scoreToAddOfTeam2.text = [self autocompleteOthersTeamPointsToAdd:stringToValidate];

        } else {

            self.scoreToAddOfTeam1.text = [self autocompleteOthersTeamPointsToAdd:stringToValidate];

        }

    } else {

        if (textField == self.scoreToAddOfTeam1) {

            self.scoreToAddOfTeam2.text = nil;

        } else {

            self.scoreToAddOfTeam1.text = nil;

        }

    }



    return YES;

}

-(NSString *) autocompleteOthersTeamPointsToAdd: (NSString *) stringBasedToCalculate {

    NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)100 - [stringBasedToCalculate integerValue]];

    return myString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change the implementation of UIUndoManager in your application. check this tutorial [here](http://nshipster.com/nsundomanager/)

If you don't want to handle shake to undo in your app then you can disable it using :

```
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationSupportsShakeToEdit = NO;
```